# Los operandos no se pudieron transmitir junto a causa de dimensiones que aún parecen ser las mismas

Tags: python

Intenté calcular la similitud del coseno entre dos columnas de un dataframe `train` siguiendo [este tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-question-answering-system-part-1-9388aadff507) :

```
train["diff"] = (train["quest_emb"] - train["sent_emb"])**2
```

Sin embargo, parece que tengo un error al calcular la diferencia de las dos columnas del marco de datos.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in safe_na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
   1032             with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
-> 1033                 return na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
   1034         except Exception:

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in na_op(x, y)
   1011         try:
-> 1012             result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)
   1013         except TypeError:

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, use_numexpr, **eval_kwargs)
    204     if use_numexpr:
--> 205         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
    206     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
     64     with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
---> 65         return op(a, b)
     66 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,4096) (7,) 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-af28fc11a9d3> in <module>()
----> 1 predicted = predictions(train)

<ipython-input-80-1699cf33d87c> in predictions(train)
      2 
      3     train["cosine_sim"] = train.apply(cosine_sim, axis = 1)
----> 4     train["diff"] = (train["quest_emb"] - train["sent_emb"])**2
      5     train["euclidean_dis"] = train["diff"].apply(lambda x: list(np.sum(x, axis = 1)))
      6     del train["diff"]

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(left, right)
   1067             rvalues = rvalues.values
   1068 
-> 1069         result = safe_na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
   1070         return construct_result(left, result,
   1071                                 index=left.index, name=res_name, dtype=None)

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in safe_na_op(lvalues, rvalues)
   1035             if is_object_dtype(lvalues):
   1036                 return libalgos.arrmap_object(lvalues,
-> 1037                                               lambda x: op(x, rvalues))
   1038             raise
   1039 

pandas/_libs/algos_common_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.algos.arrmap_object()

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in <lambda>(x)
   1035             if is_object_dtype(lvalues):
   1036                 return libalgos.arrmap_object(lvalues,
-> 1037                                               lambda x: op(x, rvalues))
   1038             raise
   1039 

    ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,4096) (130318,)
```

4096 corresponde a los vectores construidos por la función del codificador  con GloVe y 130318 corresponde a la cantidad de líneas del marco de datos.

Las dos columnas se ven así:

```
    sent_emb                                            quest_emb
0   [[0.030376578, 0.044331014, 0.081356354, 0.062...   [[0.01491953, 0.021973763, 0.021364095, 0.0393...
1   [[0.030376578, 0.044331014, 0.081356354, 0.062...   [[0.04444952, 0.028005758, 0.030357722, 0.0375...
2   [[0.030376578, 0.044331014, 0.081356354, 0.062...   [[0.03949683, 0.04509903, 0.018089347, 0.07667...
   ...
```

El objetivo es crear un aprendizaje sin supervisión. El código completo pero no actualizado [es sobre Github](https://github.com/aswalin/SQuAD/blob/master/unsupervised.ipynb).

No parcece que el numero de filas de `quest_emb` es distinto del `sent_emb`. En efecto :

```
print("len(train[\"quest_emb\"])",len(train["quest_emb"]))
print("len(train[\"sent_emb\"])",len(train["sent_emb"]))

len(train["quest_emb"]) 130318
len(train["sent_emb"]) 130318
```

#### Actualizacion :

Cuando trato de ver qué hay en una línea de uno y el otro me doy cuenta de que la estructura no es la misma:

```
>>> print(train["quest_emb"][0])
[[0.01491953 0.02197376 0.02136409 ... 0.01360919 0.03114151 0.03259924]]

>>> print(train["sent_emb"][0])
[array([0.03037658, 0.04433101, 0.08135635, ..., 0.06764812, 0.04971079,
   0.02240689], dtype=float32), array([0.05260669, 0.04548098, 0.0382337 , ..., 0.04823414, 0.07656007,
   0.03501297], dtype=float32), array([0.0502927 , 0.04480611, 0.02038252, ..., 0.03942193, 0.03132772,
   0.04595207], dtype=float32), array([0.06769167, 0.03393815, 0.0625218 , ..., 0.05555448, 0.03059104,
   0.03422254], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: Para analizar qué tipo de datos son los operandos , con la función type para saber si son dict o arrays. Ejemplo: print(type(train["sent_emb"][0]))

Comment: @JhovannyUribe Si `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` por las preguntas y
`<class 'list'>`

Comment: Entonces tocaría o transformar los arreglos, o sino hacer la resta manualmente recorriendolos

Comment: @JhovannyUribe intenté transformar `train["sent_emb"]` en np.array pero `train["quest_emb"] - np.asarray(train["sent_emb"])` también se estrelló. No creo que transformar los arreglos puede arreglar el problema porque. Pienso que el problema es que hay más de 130,000 líneas.

Comment: Podría mirar este ejemplo de operaciones https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html ,si es posible tener el código en GitHub para correrlo sería mejor. Es un problema en la operación se quiere restar las matrices? Si sí revisar numpy.substract

Comment: @JhovannyUribe De acuerdo, voy a compartir el código. Es parte de un proyecto de aprendizaje no supervisado que se puede encontrar [aquí](https://github.com/aswalin/SQuAD/blob/master/unsupervised.ipynb)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Significado de: ValueError with shapes or dimensions](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401368/significado-de-valueerror-with-shapes-or-dimensions)